# Git hanging while cloning source

Tags: git

I am cloning firmware source using `git clone` but during the operation my Internet connection went down. I immediately restored the connection, but now the git clone process is hanging.

Can I kill this clone process and start it again? Since a lot of data has already been fetched, will the new `git clone` resume with the unfetched data?

I don't want to lose my previously fetched data in the process of a new git clone.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, git doesn't <strike>(yet)</strike><sup>1</sup> support interrupting and resuming `clone` or `fetch` operations.

See these answers:
[Does git-clone have resume capability?](https://superuser.com/a/512198/176100),
[pause git clone and resume later?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805382/1114687),
[How to resume a git pull/clone after a hung up unexpectedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738344/1114687)

<sub>1: This was [proposed to be implemented during Google's Summer of Code 2009](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SoC2009Ideas#Restartable_Clone), but apparently they [never saw it through](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Continue-git-clone-after-interruption-tp3458217p3459750.html).</sub>